# Javascript case statement using variables

Tags: switch-statement

I have a situation where the information I am looking, each record has its own metrics. For this reason, the metrics/thresholds are contains with the a table and assigned to a variable. In order to display these properly with their own formatting (i.e. Red Threshold = Red), I need to be able to run either an If/Then or Switch statement against the variable. This is what I coded as a test:

```
switch (true) {
    case (txtYel_Threshold):    //    represents for this one test:  97.7 > 97 && 97.7 < 98
        ctx.CurrentItem.Comments = '<div style="display:block; width:110px;">YELLOW</div>';
        break;
    default:
        ctx.CurrentItem.Comments = '<div style="display:block; width:110px;">Did not work</div>';
        break;
}
```

Unfortunately the javascript does not recognize the text within the txtYel_Threshold variable. It works perfectly fine if I type out the statement but not when trying to use the variable with the statement in it. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to do this using the variable (again, because each record has its own metrics and therefore cannot be written in code directly)?

I would appreciate any and all assistance or feedback! Thanks.

Comment: you have to split the variable txtYel_Threshold in more part and rewrite the first case ex.case(txtYel_Threshold_part1 >txtYel_Threshold_part2 && txtYel_Threshold_part3 <txtYel_Threshold_part4) if you want use the "variable txtYel_Threshold". For each variable txtYel_Threshold_part<x> there is a number

Comment: Thank you - I'm trying to figure how best to do this. the txtYel_Threshold contains "> 97 && 97.7 <" (the 98 comes from another field) and every threshold can be very different. Not all include the && as well. I will have to think about how best to break it up but if you or anyone has any suggestions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, perhaps there is a better way. This method works, but does not allow me to use a variable in place of the operator (rather than '1 > 0' I need to use something like 'var1 var2 var3' because the metrics are different. There are some instances where 1 would be RED (bad) and others where 1 is GREEN (good).

```
// YELString includes statement such as '> 97 and < 98'
var YELString = ctx.CurrentItem.Yellow_Threshold;
var YELString = YELString.replace(/\and/g, "&&");
var YELArray = new Array();
YELArray = YELString.split(" ");

// GRNString includes statement such as '>= 98'
var GRNString = ctx.CurrentItem.Green_Threshold;
var GRNArray = new Array();
GRNArray = GRNString.split(" ");

// REDString includes statement such as '< 97'
var REDString = ctx.CurrentItem.Red_Threshold;
var REDArray = new Array();
REDArray = REDString.split(" ");

switch (true) {
    case (numCurrentMetric == "100" || numCurrentMetric >= GRNArray[1]):
        ctx.CurrentItem.Comments = 'Green';
        break;
    case (numCurrentMetric < REDArray[1]):
        ctx.CurrentItem.Comments = 'Red';
        break;
    case (numCurrentMetric > YELArray[1] && numCurrentMetric < YELArray[4]):
        ctx.CurrentItem.Comments = 'Yellow';
        break;
    default:
        ctx.CurrentItem.Comments = 'NONE';
        break;
}
```

Again, thank you for any assistance.

Comment: if you want check also the simbol >(major) and <(minor) then you to have to put this simbol in a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. In the example above, where the field reads '> 97 and < 98', the operator (in this case greater than and less than) are already assigned to the variable YELArray(0) and YELArray(3), are they not? i.e. 0=>, 1=97, 2=&&, 3=< and 4=98. numCurrentMetric is what I'm testing against. Something like... numCurrentMetric YELArray[0] YELArray[1] YELArray[2] numCurrentMetric YELArray[3] YELArray[4]) is logical but does not work. Also, I cannot hardcode the greater than and less than because the next record the operators could be different.